# Special Matrix $2$-norm and F-norm Inequalities

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

This is a homework problem for my Numerical Linear Algebra course.  It states the following:

If A is an $m\times m$  nonsingular matrix, prove the following:

(1)$\|A+(A^{*})^{-1}\| _{2} \ge 2$

(2)$\|A+(A^{*})^{-1}\| _{F} \ge 2\sqrt{m}$

I began this proof by using the SVD of A. That is $A=U\sum V^{*}$ where U and V are unitary matrices and $\sum$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of the singular values of A (in non-decreasing order). This gives the following for (1)

$\|A+(A^{*})^{-1}\| _{2}=\|U\sum V^{*}+((U\sum V^{*})^{*})^{-1}\| _{2}=\|U\sum V^{*}+U\sum^{-1} V^{*}\| _{2}$

which simplifies to

$\|U(\sum +\sum^{-1})V^{*}\|_{2}$

But since $U$ and $V$ are unitary we get

$\|U(\sum +\sum^{-1})V^{*}\|_{2}=\|\sum +\sum^{-1}\|_{2}$

and at this point I am stuck. I tried using that $\|\sum +\sum^{-1}\|_{2}$ is a diagonal matrix to calculate the matrix $2$-norm but that has not gotten me anywhere. Is there an extremely obvious next step that I am not seeing? Or do my prior calculations have a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work for (1) is correct. To complete it, just note that using AM-GM inequality you can conclude that the diagonal entries of $\Sigma +\Sigma ^{-1}$ are all greater than or equal to two. Actually, (2) follows from the same observation as well.

Comment: Okay! That makes sense. Thank you!